# For loop not terminating - Android

Tags: android, for-loop

I don't know why but my for loop won't 'stop' when its reached the truth of the termination statement.

```
for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++){
             edittext.setText("");
             EasyGame();
             //if(i==10){
                 //Game.this.finish();

             //}
         }
```

EasyGame() is an arithmetic method, just adds two numbers together. I tried using the if statement shown above, but it still wouldn't do anything, and if it did it would call finish() after the first question!

If someone would be kind to help me I would be grateful.

EDIT:

```
public void EasyGame(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    final int a = (int) rand.nextInt(20)+1;
    final int b = (int) rand.nextInt(20)+1;
    String aString = Integer.toString(a);
    String bString = Integer.toString(b);
    String display = aString + " + " + bString + " =";
    questionLabel.setText(display);
    c = a + b;


        }
```

that for loop is inside a switch/case, which deals with onClick() for buttons

Comment: do you can send the EasyGame() method to I see?

Comment: Could you post the actual content of the EasyGame() method?

Comment: i'm sure that if `i=1` then `i==10` would not return true unless your machine is trying to drive you crazy

Comment: comment your `EasyGame();` method and then check is this loop problem or what..??

Comment: I ran the code in a fresh test project, and it works perfectly. Try doing a clean build and seeing if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very difficult to say without seeing more code, but what you have posted alone is inherently flawed because you're trying to continuously update a UI element within a loop. If that loop is running on the UI thread, then the system isn't going to be able to redraw any UI elements such as your `edittext` until the loop (and whatever containing callback method) exits.

Therefore, when you say *"I tried using the if statement shown above, but it still wouldn't do anything, and if it did it would call finish() after the first question!"* I make the assumption that you're believing that the loop is only iterating once because you only ever see `edittext` display whatever is passed in the last ever `.setText()` call.

Comment: I don't see that as a problem, it redraws and stuff fine, I just can't get it to stop once i = 10

Comment: ooh I get it, so your saying that even though I'm seeing the different equations, its only iterating once?

Comment: No but that can't be true can it, my edittext.setText(""); still clears the EditText, so it must mean its looping?

Comment: `.setText()` completely *replaces* the text that is being displayed by the `TextView` / `EditText`.

Comment: Yea I can see that, its doing its job, but the for loop won't stop at 11

Comment: So what happens when you step through with the debugger? How many iterations is the loop actually doing?

Comment: Okay I debugged it, its doing 10 and then it exits the loop, but now I'm confused as to whether its doing 10 at the speed of light or not.

Comment: The loop is iterating over as fast as the processor can run it, such that it's probably completed within a few milliseconds. I can't see anything in your loop that is intended to produce any sort of a delay that would enable you to see the result of each successive `.setText()`. And even if you did have such a delay, then as stated in my answer, you would **not** see the updates because your loop is holding up the main UI thread, meaning that the system can't actually update any of your `Views` until the loop exits.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Do you have any possible solutions? I'm not sure how to fix this, been at it for hours

Answer (score 0):

I dont see anything wrong with that code. The only possible problem is that your counter is being decremented somewhere (for example inside EasyGame();), or the problem is somewhere else

Comment: The counter is a local variable. EasyGame() should not be able to access/modify it.

Answer (score 0):

In the lack of provided code, I assume that your indefinite loop is happening inside EasyGame() method

Answer (score 0):

The loop probably only runs once, and then it gets halted by a never ending loop in EasyGame().

Note: Don't use initial capitalized letters for methods, it's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Trevor Page, and i'll try and clarify :

your code, if it runs on a callback on the UI thread, could be calling itself by generating a callback when you are clearing the first textView or modifying the second.

Also, what do you mean by 'it won't stop' ? I don't quite see what you are trying to do here, since you erase 10 times the content of a textView and replace 10 times the content of another one.

Comment: I'm trying to display/answer 10 mathematical questions. I'm using my own created button as an 'enter' button which displays right/wrong answer, so every time I press the button it will use this for loop to generate a new question and clear the edittext so I can enter a new answer. What I mean is it won't stop calling the easyGame() method after it has reached 11, its like an infinite loop